# Passing a named vector into str_replace_all to replace multiple patterns

Tags: r

I know that I am able to use `stringr::str_replace_all` to perform multiple pattern replacements as shown below:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- data.frame(val = c("Apples, Bananas, Kiwis", 
                          "Apples, Bananas"))
dat %>% 
  mutate(val = str_replace_all(val, c("Apples" = "1", "Bananas" = "2", "Kiwis" = "3")))
```

However, if I try and do this with a named vector, I get an error message:

```
dat_lookup <- c("Apples", "Bananas", "Kiwis")
dat %>% 
  mutate(val = str_replace_all(val, c(dat_lookup[1] = "1", dat_lookup[2] = "2", dat_lookup[3] = "3")))
```

Does anyone know how I can do this with a named vector? This would allow me to avoid creating a separate `str_replace_all` statement for each term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a named vector with `setNames`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
dat %>% 
   mutate(val = str_replace_all(val, 
       setNames(as.character(1:3), dat_lookup)))
```

-output

```
    val
1 1, 2, 3
2    1, 2
```